# Host Vb .Exe on Sharepoint Site

Tags: vb.net, sharepoint

i want to host a vb project from a sharepoint folder instead of having it locally installed.

I am still new at this, but I only need to host the files in the same folder on sharepoint right? And then whoever can just click the .exe file, correct?

Sorry if this is a dumb question!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to display the application within SharePoint or just store it there?

Comment: Just store it there, so that anyone can find it. I do think this thread might be the answer to my question... Searching with different verbiage yielded better results.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630779/vb-net-app-without-installation    Is this the correct info i need?

Comment: Well you can run an application which was developed in VB.net without an Installation but that's not the Point. SharePoints just isn't meant to store or display applications, but I might provide you a solution soon. For further understanding, what version of SP do you use?

Comment: 2013 is the version of SP we are currently using

Comment: You can publish with ClickOnce and the publish location can be SharePoint.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in the comment SharePoint isn't meant to store or even display applications (.exe). What started as a security measure is now part of the philosophy of MS SharePoint. Here's a list of all [filetypes SP13 will block by default.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262496.aspx)

Back to your question. There is a trick how you still can upload an .exe to SharePoint:

1. Store the application in a folder
2. Zip the folder
3. Upload the zipped folder to a document library
4. Display the library on the desired site

For the future..

- As there is a "Silverlight Webpart" - develop silverlight application if you know from the beginning that you want to display them on SharePoint.
- Another trick: Publish your application on a host server. Then use the "Site Viewer WebPart" and point it to your application
- Last one, although I wouldn't suggest it.. You can develop a .wpf-application and simply upload it as the file-type isn't blocked. But to embed the resources is just a pain in the ass..

There are for sure many other ways to do this.. Those are just the most practical ones I know if you already developed the application. The best solution is of course to create your own WebPart..

Comment: i will go through these in a bit and post feedback. Thanks in advance for your help :)